# How to run a parallel program over multiple computers (user specified IP addresses)?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I am new to parallel programming. I researched a lot about using MPI and Windows HPC server's SOA programming model. But now I am more confused than ever. The task at hand is to run a program over multiple computers (IP address will be provided by the user), this program takes an input file full of millions of strings and extracts certain regions. I have completed the programming (in C# & .net4 fw) and have successfully tested it on a single computer. But the problem is that I have to make it parallel in order to speed things up. I just want somebody to show me the direction towards an approach that doesn't involve using MPI. I hope my question is clear enough.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to instantiate some behaviour on the target machines that will need to be open and listening for your requests. I suggest you [investigate WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784) for communicating across your network.

Depending on your environment, security is often an interesting hurdle for this type of project.

Comment: I think i'll delve in to WCF, my problem requires a solution where user doesnt have to install third party services. This is the reason why I am trying to avoid HPC and MPI. Biologists in general are not ideal end users!!! ... So I want to make it as simple as just enterning the IP and scheduling the partitioned data processing on those CPUs. Thanks a lot for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

You could try [Dryad](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Dryad/). It includes a LINQ-like API.

Comment: Dryad has been [discontinued](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/microsoft/microsoft-drops-dryad-puts-its-big-data-bets-on-hadoop/11226).

Answer (score 0):

You could try reworking your application to use silverlight as client processors.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/gridcomputing.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, one solution is to change your program so that it listens on some port for work to do, and get it running on a bunch of computers.  Then you want a job submitter running on one or more machines.  The submitter can receive IP addresses corresponding to a subset of the computers running your program, and then communicate with the already-running instances of your program, giving them any information they don't already have about which portion of work they're to do.

The worker program, running on many computers, is a "service", and the job submitter program is a "client".